# Validate text field to hold only digits

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way to check whether a textbox field contains just digits and not alphabetic or special characters?  I need to have the user enter a player's Uniform Number, but need to allow the user to enter "00" through "99".  The "00" entry can't be converted to 0 so using a number box doesn't work.

Comment: I closed this question as it looks as a support ticket, not as practical, detailed question. See [tour], [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I work for Cognito Forms support.  We do not currently have that capability, **but** that exact functionality is being tested right now and will be shipping soon.  If you would like, you can enter a support request (attention my id) and I can let you know exactly when it goes live.

Comment: I no longer work for Cognito Forms, but I can tell you that the functionality is already there.